# Что в этих иллюстрациях выступает в значении сказуемого?

Tags: лексикография

*Ниже приводится иллюстративный материал из словаря Ожегова и Шведовой с указанием заглавных слов.*

А.

1. **СДУТЬ**: *Как ветром сдуло кого-н.* (в знач. сказ.; исчез быстро, сразу; разг.).
2. **ЖАРКИЙ**: *Ни жарко ни холодно кому-н.* (в знач. сказ.; все равно, безразлично; разг.). *Небу жарко* (в знач. сказ.; о чьих-н. энергичных, активных действиях).

Правильно ли я понимаю, что эти иллюстрации должны были попасть в  раздел устойчивых выражений (после ромба)?

Б.

1. **УДОБНЫЙ**: *Удобно ли* (в знач. сказ.) *задать такой вопрос?*
2. **МУДРЁНЫЙ**: *Не мудрено* (в знач. сказ.), *что он рассердился* (легко понять, что...).

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в значении сказуемого выступают *"удобно ли"* и *"не мудрено"*, а не *"удобно"* и *"мудрено"*?

В.

1. **ОТКРЫТЬ**: *Открыто!* (в знач. сказ.: не заперто, можно входить).
2. **ПОТРЯСАЮЩИЙ**: *Потрясающе!* (в знач. сказ.; прекрасно, очень хорошо; разг.).
3. **СВОБОДНЫЙ**: *Здесь свободно?* (в знач. сказ.; это место не занято?).

Правильно ли я понимаю, что эти иллюстрации стоит выделить в отдельные значения по аналогии с *берегись!, мысль!, началось!, остановитесь!, отставить!, подожди!, чудеса!, эврика!* и др.?

Answer (score 1):

1. Фразеологизм КАК ВЕТРОМ СДУЛО. Разг. Обычно сов. прош. вр. Быстро, молниеносно, мгновенно исчез (исчезло). Его как ветром сдуло. Сказуемое "как ветром сдуло".
2. Сказуемые здесь "удобно и мудрено".

В состав сказуемого входят только  формообразующие частицы: да здравствует, сказал бы, пусть грянет буря.
Модальные частицы, указывающие на отношение к действительности или к сообщению, выражающие волеизъявления говорящего и т.д., тесно примыкают к сказуемому, например: Не пылит дорога, не дрожат листы... (Л.); Разве я говорю что-нибудь дурное? (М. Г.);

http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-137.htm

Comment: А разве в "не мудрено" модальная частица не примыкает тесно к сказуемому?

Comment: Модальные частицы примыкают к сказуемому, но не входят в его состав, так как не являются формообразующими (не участвуют в образовании наклонения глагола). В то же время при разборе предложения называется, например,  словосочетание (частица+ глагол), но говорится, что частица НЕ находится при сказуемом.